# Memory Limit exceedeed when printing a path of a dijkstra in Java

Tags: java

I'm getting a memory limit exceeded when I submit my code on codeforces. Evrything seems right to me.
I tried to print using iterative method and recursion method but getting the same error
Here's a link of code http://codeforces.com/contest/20/submission/28935755
This is my code:

```
 int[] shortest(int src){
    PriorityQueue<Node1> p = new PriorityQueue<>();
    initialize(src);
    p.offer(new Node1(src, 0));
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[this.v+1];

    while (!p.isEmpty()){
        Node1 node = p.poll();
        int u = node.getNode();
        int weight = node.getWeight();
        if (u == this.v-1)
            return parent;
        if (weight > distances[u])
            continue;
        if (visited[u])
            continue;
        visited[u] = true;
        Iterator<Node1> it = adj[u].iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            Node1 n = it.next();
            int vert = n.getNode();
            int w = n.getWeight();
            if (distances[vert] > distances[u] + w){
                distances[vert] = distances[u] + w;
                parent[vert] = u;

            }
            p.offer(new Node1(vert, distances[vert]));
        }
     }
     return null;
}

static void printPath(int[] path, int vert){
    if (vert == -1){
        return;
    }
    printPath(path, path[vert]);

    System.out.print(vert + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could visit your nodes inside while, something like:

```
 while (it.hasNext()){
        Node1 n = it.next();
        int vert = n.getNode();
        if( !visited[vert] || (visited[vert] && (distances[vert] > distances[u] + w)){
            visited[vert] = true;
            int w = n.getWeight();
            if (distances[vert] > distances[u] + w){
                distances[vert] = distances[u] + w;
                parent[vert] = u;

            }
            p.offer(new Node1(vert, distances[vert]));
       }
    }
```

with this you save a lot of memory because only inset nodes when it's necessary